# DEFAULT NOW() does not longer work in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Status: Solved, the problem was not with the function itself but that it does not fire when new objects are saved from QGIS to PostGIS DB. Trigger/rule will be needed in this case

I have a table with a timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
geom geometry(MultiLineString,25832),
created date DEFAULT now()
)
```

This worked when I created it, but it has stopped working. I no longer have my date field automatically field in when I add a new geometry to my table. 
Any idea why this is not working?
Should I use a rule instead?

Edit: I am logged in as a superuser

Thanks

Comment: which SQL-Server do you use?

Comment: it is the postGIS server

Comment: Just checked - postgres 9.3.7-0ubuntu0 working properly. which version are you using? maybe it's case of cast? now() is returning timestamp and your column is of type date? Maybe there is something in logs? If no maybe try to change logging level?

Comment: Show the insert code and what you get in `created` column.

Comment: You are probably inserting into the column. Add more details.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I was editing (constructing geometry and added metadata in QGIS). Apparently the now() function does not work if you are saving to the db from a QGIS project. I tried to use a standard INSERT INTO from the command line and then the function worked!
Thanks for you comments guys